# response.sendRedirect not working

Tags: jsp, jdbc, response

The method response.sendRedirect() is not working in my program.

The code go through and sucessfully print `out.println("wrong user");`, but the redirect to the google paged doesn't work.

```
String id="java";

try 
{
    query = "select Id from Users where Id= ?";
    ps  =Database.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
    ps.setString(1, id);
    rs  =   ps.executeQuery();

    if(rs.next())
    {
        out.println(rs.getString(1));
    }
    else 
    {
        out.println("wrong user");
        response.sendRedirect("www.google.com");
    }
    rs.close();
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    //e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.print(e);
}
```

Any answers?

Comment: are you sure that code is executed?

Comment: no sir. when i remove the comment before the out.println("Wrong user"), it displays "wrong user". and stay from the same page

Comment: where is this code written? in jsp/servlet?

Comment: Also check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637990/response-sendredirect-from-jspinclude-being-ignored

Comment: @Amar is your issue resolved. if yes, and not among given answer, can you specify your own.

Answer (score 18):

You should `return` after redirecting.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
return;
```

It does not return automatically after calling sendRedirect().

Comment: I know it's a year later but, this worked for me. I was using it in an if-statement too, without realizing the rest of the code is still executed. In a catch-clause of a try it does still work without return. Thanks!

Comment: @RobbieVercammen: You are Wel-come. Good to hear that. :)

Comment: it is working fr me. good, small mistake i have done +1 for that

Comment: Worked for me too (7 years after the reply - I'm rewriting some legacy code).

Comment: @RafaelSantos: Happy to hear that!!

Answer (score 5):

**HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect() works like this:**

- if the URL is absolute `http://www.google.com` , it redirects to `http://www.google.com`.
- If the URL is not absolute , it redirects relative to the current URL.
  If the URL starts with `/` it redirects relative to the context root,
  Else it redirects to the current url

Based on above rules `in your case it redirects to http://currenturl/www.google.com`.

**Instead modify your code like this**

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<% response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com/"); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try providing the protocol.

```
response.sendRedirect("http://www.google.com");
return;
```