# Error in passing values from a jsp page to another

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I am a beginner.In my project I am using JSP and Mysql Workbench. I got an error in passing one value from a jsp page to another the code that I used was

`response.sendRedirect("setter.jsp?userid=<%=(rs.getInt("user_id"))%>");`

The error showing is `)` Expected But I cant identify where is the error please somebody help me.

Comment: If you are in the JSP, you can't send a redirect. Do that in a servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you need scriptlet tag, when you are already inside scriptlet. Shouldn't it be

```
response.sendRedirect("setter.jsp?userid="+rs.getInt("user_id"));
```

PS:

- As quoted in the comments, I am not sure if redirection can be done from JSP. I concentrated on the syntax.
- Use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) instead of scriptlets

Comment: Whether this removes the error doesn't matter because they won't be able to send the redirect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637990/response-sendredirect-from-jspinclude-being-ignored

Comment: Thanks @SotiriosDelimanolis I was not aware of redirection. I have edited the post

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: Response will be committed only if you include that jsp using `<jsp:include>` tag. With a normal jsp, it should work.